# Python subtleties for MATLAB users

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7, python-3.x

What are some of the most basic things that a programmer **who is used to coding in MATLAB** needs to be cautious about, when beginning to code in Python? I am not asking for an entire list of differences between MATLAB and Python, just a few very basic things that can save a beginner a few hours of debugging.

An example would be how someone used to MATLAB's `1:N` may make a mistake in python by using `range(1,N)`

Differences in concepts would be more helpful than absolute differences in specific commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NumPy site has an *excellent* list, which I won't reproduce in full here. NumPy provides basically all the basic functionality of MATLAB for Python users, so it is highly recommended if you're coming to Python from MATLAB.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150818181140/http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users)

Some highlights:

- INDEXING: MATLAB® uses one based indexing, so the initial element of a sequence has index 1. Python uses zero based indexing, so the initial element of a sequence has index 0. Confusion and flamewars arise because each has advantages and disadvantages. One based indexing is consistent with common human language usage, where the "first" element of a sequence has index 1. Zero based indexing simplifies indexing. See also a text by prof.dr. Edsger W. Dijkstra.
- LOGICOPS: & or | in Numpy is bitwise AND/OR, while in Matlab & and | are logical AND/OR. The difference should be clear to anyone with significant programming experience. The two can appear to work the same, but there are important differences. If you would have used Matlab's & or | operators, you should use the Numpy ufuncs logical_and/logical_or.